# downloading akka api jar for scala using sbt

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I am trying to download akka api jar for scala using sbt, I have added the following line to the build.sbt:
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" %% "akka-actor" % "2.4.9" withJavadoc()

Since akka is available in both Java and Scala, it is downloading the akka api jar for the Java language rather than that for Scala language.

I wonder how does one download the akka api jar for scala.

Comment: I'm thinking it's the same jar file -- regardless if it's for Scala or Java ... right?

Comment: I don't know but I think the scala api is a little bit different from the java api;

Comment: You have different syntax and language features for calling the Akka API -- but the API itself is the same on either Scala or Java.  

My best/only advice is to follow this tutorial as close as possible and it should show the way:

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0/intro/getting-started-first-scala.html

Comment: some of these answers shed light on this too 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20945139/differences-between-akka-scala-and-java

Comment: I know there's not much difference between the two but things like implicit parameters and curried functions are just not available in java and looking at the java api will not give you any clue as to whether any parameter is implicit and the curried function calls are entirely different.